# Why do I get URI Mismatch for one account and not another?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

Using Azure.   My registered app is a Public Client (It's a desktop Appplication).

The code below works just fine under "USERA"'s account.

However, running the same code as "USERB" I get the following exception

**MSAL.NetCore.4.42.0.0.MsalClientException:
ErrorCode: loopback_response_uri_mismatch
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: Redirect Uri mismatch.  Expected (/favicon.ico) Actual (/).
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.AcquireAuthorizationAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, RequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceInternalAsync(IWebUI webUi, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.AuthCodeRequestComponent.FetchAuthCodeAndPkceVerifierAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.GetTokenResponseAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)**

```
              pubApp = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
                                .WithLogging(Log, LogLevel.Verbose, true)
                                .WithAuthority(config.Authority)
                                .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost:12345/")                               
                                .Build();

   /** 
    * A call to Graph API calls the following
    */
                    authResult = await clientApp.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                        .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)
                        .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                        .ExecuteAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Please check the redirect URI that you are giving in the code.***

> If your app pops up a window with no address bar, then it is using the
> "**embedded browser**"

For desktop applications using **embedded** browser, Microsoft recommend using redirect URI as:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient`

> If your app brings your system's **default** browser (such as Edge,
> Chrome, Firefox, etc.) to visit Microsoft login portal, then it is
> using the "**system browser**".

For desktop applications using **system** browser, Microsoft recommend using redirect URI as:
`http://localhost`

In the code, you have mentioned `.WithUseEmbeddedWebView`(**false**) which means you are not using **embedded** browser.

Please check if both user accounts are using different **system** browsers.

Try changing redirect URI in **.WithRedirectUri()** field to something like below as a **workaround**:

`"http://localhost:12345"` or
`"http://localhost"` or
`"https://localhost"`

Please find below references if they are helpful.

**References:**
[Ref1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#redirect-uri-for-public-client-apps),
[Ref2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-app-registration#redirect-uris),
[Ref3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url#:%7E:text=%20In%20this%20approach:%20%201%20Create%20a,state%20parameter%20back%20to%20the%20application.%20More)

Comment: Thank you.   I'd done some reading up on this last night and it's nice to see an answer that confirms the documentation.